# Convert data to string after reading from a xls or xlsx file in python

Tags: python, django, xls, xlsx, openpyxl

I am writing a function which is used to read data from an xls/xlsx file and insert into db. But the problem is after reading the data from the cells of the xls file the value becomes float type.

Below is my sample data from xls file :

```
Zip     Zone
35096       
31723   1
35963       
36037   D 21
36849   HANDLE
```

I am using `from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook` to read the xls file. After I have read the values from **Zip** and **Zone** column when I am inserting these values to DB all the numeric values becomes float type, but it should be saved as string. The type of above 2 db column is **VARCHAR**

I have also printed the values of above 2 column after reading from xls file in the terminal and here is the result :

**ZIP**

```
==========
<type 'float'>
35096.0
==========
<type 'float'>
31723.0
==========
<type 'float'>
35963.0
==========
<type 'float'>
36037.0
==========
<type 'float'>
36849.0
```

**ZONE**

```
==========
<type 'NoneType'>
==========
<type 'float'>
1.0
==========
<type 'NoneType'>
==========
<type 'unicode'>
D 21
==========
<type 'unicode'>
HANDLE
```

**MY CODE**

```
try:
    book = load_workbook(filename=file_path, use_iterators=True)
    ws = book.worksheets[0]
except:
    return 'Error message'


for row in (ws.iter_rows()):
    zip = row[0].internal_value
    zone = row[1].internal_value
```

Other info: I am using python 2.6 and on an Ubuntu machine
How to solve this.

Comment: Could you show the code you are using for reading an excel file?

Comment: @alecxe: I have added my code down to the question.

Comment: What if you just cast values to strings: `zip = str(row[0].internal_value)` and `str(row[1].internal_value)`?

Comment: I have already tried convert the data using str(), but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

If zip is a sequence try

```
zip = [str(fl) for fl in row[0].internal_value[:]]
```